# Magento 2.2.2 add to cart not working after server change

Tags: addtocart, server-setup, magento2.2.2

Add to cart was not working on local server and it was fixed by changing the ***base_url*** in **database** from "http://localhost/magento2" to "http://127.0.0.1/magento2".

Now after all design changes when this installation was moved to live server, we made the respective changes in DB, env.php and cleared cache.

Every link and all functionalities are working fine except 'Add to cart' functionality has stopped working.

Following are the issues with 'Add to cart':

1. On category page (*product listing page*): when '**Add to cart**' button is clicked, it directly takes to '**cart**' page without adding product to cart.
2. *On Product detail page*: When clicked on '**Add to cart**' button, its text changes to '**Adding**' and it stays the same and product is never added to cart.

There are no errors in console for both of the above scenarios.

**Following I have tried:**

*Deleted following directories:*

- pub\static
- var\cache
- var\page_cache
- var\view_preprocessed
- var\composer_home

*Ran these commands using ssh:*

- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

*And following commands to give magento's default permissions to directories:*

- `sudo chmod -R a+wX pub`
- `sudo chmod -R a+wX var`
- `sudo chmod -R a+wX app`
- `sudo chmod -R a+wX app/etc`
- `sudo chmod -R a+wX generated`

Updated **cookie_lifetime** to **86400** in admin.

Cleared cache from admin.

But still issue persists.

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: Would you see the Magento logs?

Comment: Please, check corresponding request in the network tab in console of your browser. Perhaps you can find responce with a text of the error returned by your web-server.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau: I have checked it there are no errors in network or console when clicked on add to cart.

Comment: Can you see the request? What is returned in the response?

Comment: In my instalation occur the same problem when I move to php71u. I rebuild my docker images with php70u and now I can add product in my cart again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using apache? Make sure .htaccess file is been read  or else try adding index.php to url.

Also make sure Php rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: Tried with index.php still not working and rewrites module is already enabled.

Comment: hey this is worked for me. I have given permissions again then it worked normally.

Thank you for view on this